# What's the most efficient way to update an optional object property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following object. The data comes in from 2 separate messages, both of which have a timestamp and icao (id number). However, one message has ident info (callsign) and the other has aircraft position.

```
export interface AircraftInfo {
  timestamp: Date
  icao: string
  ident?: {
    callsign: string
  }
  pos?: {
    lat: number
    lon: number
    altitude: number
  }
}
```

As the data comes in, I update the necessary sections. What's the most elegant way to update the `pos` property? I suspect if it already exists, the best thing to do is to update individual properties rather than overwriting with a new object. If it doesn't, a new object has to be assigned.

This results in code like this:

```
  // update position if position exists, otherwise create position with position
  if (info.pos) {
    info.pos.altitude = altitude
    info.pos.lon = lon
    info.pos.lat = lat
  } else {
    info.pos = { altitude, lon, lat }
  }
```

This feels a little clunky. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Where do those three variables come from? If they're already part of an object, just assign that object to `info.pos`.

Comment: "*I suspect if it already exists, the best thing to do is to update individual properties rather than overwriting with a new object*" - no, as you saw this results in clunky code.

Comment: "info.pos = { altitude, lon, lat }" <-This line is not valid JavaScript

Comment: No need for the conditional. As Bergi mentioned, I'm not sure why you don't want to just always overwrite `pos` with a new object. You should just be doing `info.pos = { altitude, lon, lat }`.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Why not?

Comment: @DaveNewton JavaScript objects need a name and a value, a la info.pos = {"altitude" : altitude, ...}

Comment: @ControlAltDel https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer, circa ES2015 iirc.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is less "clunky"

```
if (!info.pos) info.pos = {};
info.pos.altitude = altitude;
info.pos.lon = lon;
info.pos.lat = lat;
```

Comment: `info.pos ??= {}`

Comment: @JaredSmith `??=` is that a valid operator in JavaScript? I couldn't find documentation for it.

Comment: [Yup, it's legit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment). You can try it in the browser console on this very page.

Comment: @ControlAltDel https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment

Comment: This creates a new object for pos. From a strictly theoretical perspective, there's no need to create a new object and GC the old object just to update lat/lon. Another issue I see is that if someone is holding on to the previous reference of info.pos, they'll have the old object.

Comment: @Kon that's incorrect: this code only creates a new object for `.pos` if one doesn't already exist. So there won't be any extra allocations or stale references.

Comment: @JaredSmith, yes, you're correct. I missed the `if` in the beginning. The only problem with the first line is that typescript will complain about `info.pos = {}`. I realize I did not tag with with TS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you may need a spread operator (this apprach brings immutability as well):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wbc2w2?file=index.ts

```
interface AircraftInfo {
  timestamp: Date;
  icao: string;
  ident?: {
    callsign: string;
  };
  pos?: {
    lat: number;
    lon: number;
    altitude: number;
  };
}

const aircraftInfo: AircraftInfo = {
  timestamp: undefined,
  icao: '',
};

aircraftInfo.ident = {
  ...aircraftInfo.ident,
  callsign: 'callsign',
};

aircraftInfo.pos = {
  ...aircraftInfo.pos,
  lat: 1,
  lon: 2,
  altitude: 3,
};

console.log(aircraftInfo);
```

Comment: This creates a new object for pos. From a strictly theoretical perspective, there's no need to create a new object and GC the old object just to update lat/lon. Another issue I see is that if someone is holding on to the previous reference of info.pos, they'll have the old object.

Comment: Yes, you don't need another new variable reference, that's right. But on the other hand, in code of the high quality (when using framework like Angular and so on) immutability comes into play.